# Can not login after change limits.conf

Tags: linux, centos

I am update `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
* soft nofile 10000000
* hard nofile 10000000
```

I forgot to change `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
fs.file-max = 10000000 
fs.nr_open = 10000000
```

I can't login through SSH. Include root user.

So how should I login the server(ssh) and fix it.

System: CentOS release 6.3

Comment: what error message you get ?

Comment: anyway, don't set fs.file-max equal to nofile in limits.conf, because nofile is a limit by user and fs.file-max is a global limit, in this way, you give power to an user to use the all file descriptor of the system.

Comment: C6.3 is end-of-life, don't run it.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to gain access back to your machine requires you to be physically near the server.

Then, you reboot the server and when grub menu shows up you hit 'e' on the first line, add in the end of the command the word "single" or just the number 1, then hit enter and then 'b' to boot that line in grub.

Then when the server starts you run:

```
mount -o remount,rw / 
mount -o remount,rw /proc
```

To remount "/" directory as read-write and allow saving files as single user mode starts with read-only filesystem.

Then you fix your `/etc/security/limits.conf` file and reboot the server.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like below?

`ssh user@server 'echo "fs.file-max = 10000000" > /etc/sysctl.conf; echo "fs.nr_open = 10000000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf'`

Also it may be problem with spawning bash, so rsync/scp of complete file could do the work.

Comment: Questions asking for clarification should be posted as comments.

Answer (score 1):

Since other answers are not complete and did not work for me, I share with you my solution. First restart the server, After BIOS load when the GRUB menu shows up, press the 'e' key for edit:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNIRE.png)

Move on  that line which starts with 'linux16', press 'ctrl+e' to go end of the line, then add `systemd.unit=emergency.target` parameter to this line, like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjJqV.png)

Press 'ctrl+x' to boot the server with added parameter. After login to sever, all files are in read only mode, so to remount the filesystem as read-write, remount root (`/`) or target directory `/etc/security/` with read and write permissions.

Finally open config file: `/etc/security/limits.conf` and edit config and restart the server.

Now you can ssh into your server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the console/Out of band access, that may let you in. Failing that restart the system and on the Console/OOB access, at the GRUB menu select one of the rescue options. Or at the grub menu edit one of the boot options and add`linux rescue` to the kernel command line which should get you to single user mode.